# How to have single login in my all other apps like Amazon do

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-kotlin

If I have 2 apps and the user had logged in one of them. How can I make the user automatically login in the other app? So, one login in either app is sufficient for accessing both of them.

For e.g. like if I have Amazon app I don't have to login in to my Amazon prime app if I am already logged in Amazon app.

Comment: Excuse me, just edited to fix general meaning :)

Comment: Did you find anything other than the deprecated APIs?

Comment: @abhishekmaharajpet Were you able to find any proper solution to this? At the moment, I can only think of Content Providers but it's a lot of boilerplate code to be implemented in both the applications.

Comment: SharedPreference as per answer below and Content providers are the only things as far as i know

Answer (score 2):

Well you just need to set same name for `android:sharedUserId` and `android:sharedUserLabel` in both of their manifest file and then you can access one application's `sharedPreference` into another

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
...
android:sharedUserId="ANYTHING" 
android:sharedUserLabel="ANYTHING_LABEL">
```

and one more thing. While accessing the sharedPreference of other application use this.

```
Context con = createPackageContext("PACKAGENAME_OF_OTHER_APP", 0);
                SharedPreferences pref = con.getSharedPreferences(
                            "YOUR_KEY", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                String your_data = pref.getString("YOUR_KEY", "No Value");
```

Comment: according to [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element) these attributes were deprecated in API 29

Comment: @sergiytikhonov Any other way available to achieve this?